# QML text rendering issue

Tags: qt, qml, text-rendering

I am displaying some text with QML on an embedded device which has a 480x272 resolution screen. The code on the embedded device runs on Linux.
Currently I am using the font called Rubik from Google, but I have tried other fonts as well and experienced the same issue or even worth.

Here is an image of what I am talking about:

[image: cut of zero]

As you can see the 0 character's right side gets cut off.

For the QML part I use the `Text` component. These are the properties I set:

```
lineHeight: 1

font.family: Style.defaultFont.font.family
font.pixelSize: Style.font_baseSize
font.letterSpacing: 1.18
font.weight: QtQuick.Font.Light
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc That is impossible, since it happens only on the embedded device and not on my desktop. This issue might or probably not related to QML? I am curious what kind of suggestions people have or if they encountered an issue like this and what was the corresponding solution.

Comment: then I recommend reporting it as a bug. :)

Comment: I've just had this case, I'll report a bug

Comment: here's the link to the bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-100453